# Revive aloe plant

Tags: leaves, diseases, aloe

When the health of Aloe leaves closest to root deteriorates, like in this image, how does one revive it? I mean when the health of the leaf is not great.

Image is not loadable.

Comment: Hi nish! It's too bad your photo won't load. By any chance does your problem look like anything in a question in the [aloe](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aloe) category? They don't all have pictures, but some do, and it might help point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Try describing how the leaves look. I agree with @pnuts, it could be too much water. Aloe needs a surprisingly low amount of water to live unless the terrain is particularly dry.

There's also this great guide to troubleshooting plants, which can help you figure out what's wrong.
http://greenhouse.kenyon.edu/troubleshooting.htm

Answer (score 1):

Shoot, try resending the photo.  One thing I can pass along is that the lower leaves are the oldest and first to go. It doesn't mean the plant is in danger at all.  We truly have to see a picture of the entire plant, the pot or environment, learn what you've been doing for watering, fertilizer, soil.  How long you've been taking care of this plant also.  Hearing that the oldest leaves on a plant even aloe has come off said plant means very little as it is so normal to all plants...what is your light situation, does your pot have a hole.  How often do you water?  Need to know far more with a few more pictures.  This is tough trying to answer questions responsibly by a photo or two and a few sentences of information.  Talk to us about why you aren't able to send a picture.  Most of the people trying to answer questions understand the details of the computer, apps and this site's restraints.  We can help you get a picture loaded.  Right now with what you've told us I don't think there is any true urgency.  Please tell us more about the care of your plant, how long you've had it, where it lives (indoors, out doors, on a shaded patio), how often you water, what you have done for fertilizer and what soil is in that pot.  Are there stones or gravel beneath the soil above the drain hole?  Is there a saucer that fills with water and your plant and pot are allowed to sit in this water...?  So many details.  Hope this helps in the meantime!